# ASP.NET microsoft access insert db error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I am recieving syntax error in insert into statement. I am using microsoft access database. here is code sample:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("measurmentdb.mdb"));
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into tbl_Users(Username,Name,Surname,Password,Email,Phonenumber,CV)values(@un,@name,@sna,@pw,@em,@pn,@cv)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@un", txtusername.Text); 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sna", txtsurname.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pw", txtpassword.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@em", txtemail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pn", txtphone.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cv", txtcv.Text);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Everything in database is in text format:

```
tbl_Users:
Username
Name
Surname
Password
Email
Phonenumber
CV
```

I could not figure out what is wrong. I would appreciate your helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NAME` and `PASSWORD` are [*reserved words*](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx) on MS Access.

Use them with square brackets like `[NAME]` and `[PASSWORD]`

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into tbl_Users(Username,[Name],Surname,[Password],Email,Phonenumber,CV)values(@un,@name,@sna,@pw,@em,@pn,@cv)", con);
```

> If a reserved word is already in use, you can avoid error messages by
>   surrounding each occurrence of the word with brackets (`[ ]`). **However,
>   the best solution is to change the name to a nonreserved word.**